# Mysql Rounding Error

Tags: mysql, rounding

Im having a problem with rounding on mysql. This is my query.

```
SELECT ROUND(8120.125,2) A, COMPUTE_DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT(13150.00,35,5,0) as B, ROUND(COMPUTE_DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT(13150.00,35,5,0),2) as C;
```

And returns

```
--------------------------------
|    A    |     B    |    C    |
--------------------------------
| 8120.13 | 8120.125 | 8120.12 |
--------------------------------
```

The custom function COMPUTE_DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT just do a division computing discounts, accepts double parameters and returns double value.

I think the result returns weird for rounding

Comment: Double? Are you aware of the difference between double and decimal (I'm not, but that's beside the point)

Comment: 'rounding' is always 'interesting' especially for floating-point numbers. here is the [mysql manual on rounding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html) it may help to explain what is happening. There is no bug in mysql numbers. That is just how floating point numbers behave.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact. The result of `compute_discounted_amount` is probably something like `8120.124999999999`, which gets printed as `8120.125`. But when you round it, it's closer to `8120.124`.

Comment: Oh shoot... if it returns `8120.124999999999` then what options do you think I can do to make it right? I need to get a result of `8120.13`. This is a pain in the ass. Hahaha!!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for enlightenment on msyql rounding... :-)

Comment: Never use `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT` if you need precision. . . particularly with money.  `DECIMAL` values are implemented for precision, and don't have this problem, while floats and doubles support storing a wide range of values in a small number of bytes, but are by nature approximate.  This is not a limitation in MySQL -- it's a limitation of floating point arithmetic in general.